# Identifying and Navigating to Storyboard View Controllers from a Table XIB

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, navigation, storyboard

*RE: iOS5 development*

I currently have a large Storyboard-web of View Controllers that all inherit the same basic class, using different images/titles for differentiation.

An example would be:

10 different VCs with the same root class, spread across a storyboard. The user 'favourites' two of these VCs into a *favourite* (mutable)array.

This array takes the value of the favourited VCs' titles and is loaded up into a table view.

Is there a way of associating a VC title with some sort of tag that can be used to segue to the relevant VC from the table view cell selection?

**In short, is there a way of assigning IDs (similar to tags) for VCs that can then be linked to a dictionary/array of each VC's name so that a user can select such a title within a table and be segued to the relevant VC?**

NOTE: the table view is a XIB, with the VCs in question being storyboarded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select a VC in IB, open up the attributes inspector.  In there you will see under the general "View Controller" tag there is a field for "Identifier"  it is this string that you can use to instantiate from the code via:

```
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourVCIdentifier"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I can see this is definitely the right direction to head in, however, I'm having difficulty referring to 'storyboard', i.e. the main storyboard. When I change it to self.storyboard, it registers but doesn't do anything. I've tried performing a preexisting segue and that doesn't seem to work either... any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm thats interesting, in my code I just refer to `self.storyboard` and that must be getting set automatically.  You must be having problems because the view controller you're attempting to call it from is loaded from a XIB instead.  Is your storyboard the main file of the app, or do you have a root XIB instead?

Comment: Storyboard's the main file... I've actually just knocked the XIB out and placed the TableVC within the storyboard to see if that helps, but it still just doesn't do anything. I've tried calling that method from a button elsewhere to rule out it being the table's fault but still nothing loads.

Comment: According to the documentation, if the view controller was instantiated in a storyboard, then the `storyboard` property of the view controller should be set to that storyboard.  Since you moved the table VC into the storyboard, have you tried doing a clean and rebuild, just to make sure?  Did you delete the XIB, or at least remove it from the project?  How is the view moving to the table VC?

Comment: That does make sense and is logical, but even after a clean build and/or using the trigger in pre-existing VCs doesn't seem to be working. I'll go through my code and see if I went wrong and try to update this within a day or too. Thanks again

Comment: Got it - forgot to push the new VC afterwards... I'll add the code to your answer as a footnote. Thanks again!

Comment: You can get the storyboard you need using [this method.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html) e.g. `[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourVCIdentifier"];`